# Equality of $is_admin for custom created role users

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, roles, admin

I have created a **site-admin** role for my client to edit page contents.

Are users under this site-admin included to **$is_admin** condition? I tested and as I see it is not unless I miss something. So, what is the equality  of $is_admin for my custom created role users?

Appreciate helps!! Thanks a lot

Comment: What $is_admin condition? Where are you getting the $is_admin variable? Can you provide some code of you checking this condition?

Comment: http://www.minezone.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/drupal-theming-cheat-sheet.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the following:

```
if (user_access('access administration pages')) {
 $variables['is_admin'] = TRUE;
}
```

According to http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess/6

But that permission is overreaching, and this really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
global $user;

if ($user->uid != 0 && in_array('some_role', $user->roles)) {
  $user_is_some_role = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: For D7, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/_template_preprocess_default_variables/7

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended that you do not check if a user has a specific role, but if the user has a specific permission. It's a basic rule in security: it's not about who you are, it's about what you're allowed to do.

The $is_admin variable is a little confusing because the name suggests that it checks for a certain role. However, the code Kevin posted shows that $is_admin is in fact checking for a permission.